# Xcode design data

Tags: swift, xcode, design-data

Can I add to my interface builder design data that appears only in design mode?

For example - add text to labels, items to a list view, pictures inside imageviews, etc., all in design mode while using Xcode. However, in runtime, none of it will appear.

If you are coming from the Android world, I'm looking for the equivalent of the "tools" xml attribute.

Comment: You have to set constraints. Maybe this tutorial helps: https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Hidden during runtime` option AFAIK. But you can use `Hidden` under `Attribute inspector`->`View`->`Drawing` to manually hide each UI elements.

Comment: I would suggest to check prepareForInterfaceBuilder() method.